# $G_1$ and $G_2$ are homeomorphic.$G_1$ have $n_1$ vertices, $m_1$ edges, $G_2$ have $n_2$ vertices, $m_2$ edges. Show $m_1 − n_1 = m_2 − n_2$.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be two homeomorphic graphs. Let $G_1$ have $n_1$ vertices and $m_1$ edges,
and let $G_2$ have $n_2$ vertices and $m_2$ edges. Show that $m_1 − n_1 = m_2 − n_2$.

Here is my proof

By the degree formula,  $\sum deg(v)=2E$

Let's say graph $G_1$ has degree $2E$ and edge $E$, since $G_1$ and $G_2$ are homeomorphic. Add $k$ vertices to $G_1$ to make it become $G_2$. The sum of degree of $G_2$ is $2E+2k$, and number of edges of $G_2$ is $E+k$

How do I proceed from here to prove that $m_1 − n_1 = m_2 − n_2$?

$\textbf{Update}$

prove that homeomorphic graphs with no vertices of degree two are isomorphic.

By definition, two graphs are  homeomorphic if they are isomorphic or
can be reduced to isomorphic graphs by a sequence of series reductions(remove vertex of degree 2). Equivalently, two graphs are homeomorphic if they can be
obtained from the same graph by a sequence of elementary subdivisions(insert vertex in the middle of an edge).

Can I just conclude that "homeomorphic graphs with no vertices of degree two are isomorphic" from the definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $G_1$ and $G_2$ are homeomorphic graphs, you can't always add vertices to one to make it become the other. For example, let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be two nonisomorphic subdivisions of $K_{1,3},$ one obtained by putting three new vertices on one of the old edges, the other by one vertex on each of the old edges. You **can** make two homeomorphic graphs isomorphic by subdividing *both* of them, or (better) by *removing* all vertices of degree $2$ from both of them.

Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be homeomorphic graphs. Let $G_i'$ be the graph obtained from $G_i$ by removing all vertices of degree two. Since removing a vertex of degree two loses one vertex and one edge, we have $|E(G_i')|-|V(G_i')|=|E(G_i)-|V(G_i)|,$ and of course $G_i'$ is homeomorphic to $G_i.$ Therefore, it will suffice to prove $|E(G_1)|-|V(G_1)|=|E(G_2)|-|V(G_2)|$ in the special case where $G_1$ and $G_2$ are homeomorphic graphs **with no vertices of degree two**. The best way do to that is to prove that **homeomorphic graphs with no vertices of degree two are isomorphic**. In fact, if there are no vertices of degree two, the homeomorphism itself (restricted to vertices) is a graph isomorphism.

Comment: I updated my solution after reading your hints. Could you take a look and provide more feedbacks? Thank you